# PHP Regular Expression Between {x,y}

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, expression

I dont have a good handle on regular expressions yet, but I was hoping someone could help me with this. I found this expression here, it's almost exactly what I need but I need to add to it

```
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/
```

I need to make sure the submitted string is between {4, 20} 4 and 20 characters long, I've looked at other simpler examples, but this expression is a tad bit more complicated. Where would I add the "{4, 20}" in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at the start to check for right number of letters like

```
/^(?=.{4,20}$)[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick fix approach that will work in any case where you need to enforce string length, regardless of the regular expression:

```
/^(?=.{4,20}$)[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/
```

Also you can use this look-ahead technique to cumulate multiple regular expressions.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
/^([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*){4,20}$/
```

Comment: @Alin Purcaru Yep, your solution looks much cleaner - hadn't really used the look-ahead technique before :)

Comment: I don't want to say your solution is not clean. I want to say it's not correct. The repeater condition states that the expression inside the grouping parentheses needs to be repeated 4 to 20 times, but that expression may have a variable number of characters.